# How to get value which has been changed per <td> in table using LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, event

i fetch this records from DB :
[image]

HTML :

```html
<template for:each={createDefaultsData} for:item="acc" for:index="index">
    <tr key={acc.key} id={acc.key}>
        <td>{index}</td>

        <td>
            <lightning-combobox
                data-index={index}
                data-id={indx}
                name="input1"
                label="Field"
                placeholder="Sélectionner un champ"
                value={acc.Field__c}
                onchange={handleChangeCaseFields}
                options={Options}
            >
            </lightning-combobox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <lightning-input-field
                data-index={index}
                data-id={indx}
                field-name="Operator__c"
                value={acc.Operator__c}
                name="input2"
                onchange={handleChange2}
            ></lightning-input-field>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input-text
                onsearchstringvaluechange={handlesearchStringvaluechange}
                search-string={input4}
                data-index={index}
                data-id={indx}
                label="Custom Lookup - Account"
                selected-name={acc.Value__c}
                recordlimit="10"
                onlookupselect={handlelookupselectaccount}
            ></input-text>
        </td>
        <td><button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={handleRowRemoveClick}>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Js :

```js
handleChange2(event) {
    this.input2 = event.target.value;
}

handleChangeCaseFields(event) {
    this.input1 = event.target.value
}
```

- Record 1 :  **Field** : Status , **Operator** = Equals , **Value** = Clos
- Record 2 : **Field** : CaseNumber , **Operator** = Equals , **Value** = 01474743

I want to build an array of changed values , let's say for Record 1 we have changed it's field to **Subject** and for record 2 we have changed the operator to **not Equal**  - i don't insert value in database i just want to build an array with existing values and values which has been changed so in our case it will be :

- Record 1 :  **Field** : Subject, **Operator** = Equals , **Value** = Clos
- Record 2 : **Field** : CaseNumber , **Operator** = Not Equals , **Value** = 01474743

How can i achieve this? how to iterate over table then stock changed values per TD ?

Comment: What's not working with your current design? Where exactly are you stuck? This site is here to help with specific problems, but it's not clear specifically what you're having trouble with.

Comment: i've mentioned what is my problem , is how to get changed values from array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set *all* of the row values into a single variable:

```
handleChange2(event) {
    this.input2 = event.target.value;
}
```

As I [previously demonstrated](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/VZgYTjQnBfHGVHILp0Uk/src/app.css?p=stories), you need to store the new values into an array:

```
this.filters[index][name] = value;
```

If you want to know what the differences are, you need to define an initial set of values when you get data from your wire method:

```
@wire(getCriterias, { listview: '$listViewId' })
handleGetFilters(response) {
  const { data } = response;
  this.filters = data.map((filter, index)=>({...filter, index}));
  this.originalValues = data;
}
```

When you want to save the "delta" changes, you can find those:

```
const modifiedFilters = this.filters
  .filter(
    (
      filter,
      index // Find rows with at least one edit
    ) =>
      Object.entries(filter).some(
        ([field, value]) => this.originalValues[index][field] !== value
      )
  )
  .map((filter, index) => ({
    Id: filter.Id,
    ...Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(filter).filter(
        // Find fields that have been modified
        ([field, value]) => this.originalValues[index][field] !== value
      )
    ),
  }));
```

This may look like a lot to unpack. However, many of these methods are all related in concept. We take something in, do something with it, and returns something out. This sort of stuff is really common in JavaScript, so you may want to study it a bit. It will save you a lot of time as you come to understand how these functions work.

- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): converts one Array into a new Array, transformed by its callback parameter. As a trivial example: `[1,2,3,4].map(x=>x*2)` returns `[2,4,6,8]`.
- [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): takes one Array, examines each index using the callback, and returns a new Array only if a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value is returned.
- [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some): takes an array, performs a callback on each index, and returns true if at least one index returns a truthy value.
- [`Object.prototype.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries): takes an Object and returns an Array of Array values, where each index in the top level Array has an Array with a length of 2, the key and value.
- [`Object.prototype.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries): performs the inverse of `Object.prototype.entries`; it converts an Array with indices that each contain an Array with a length of 2, being the key and value, and returning an Object.
- [`{ ...object }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax): `...` assigns all the properties of `object` during construction of the new object in an [Object literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: Thanks a lot can we please have a quick chat?  what's  **this.filters[index][name] = value;** ?

Comment: @Fabien I tried to chat with you yesterday, but we never ended up crossing paths. I'm going back in the chat room from yesterday. Feel free to meet me there.

Comment: do you know how to get the id of removed cell from table : `removeRow(event) {
            this.caseDefaultData.splice(event.target.dataset.index, 1);
            this.caseDefaultData = this.caseDefaultData.map((x, index)=>({...x, index, rowNumber: index+1}));`  i want to get the *ids* of removed cells ..

Comment: @Fabien The return value from `this.caseDefaultData.splice(...)` will be the removed elements. You can check that for the Id value of the removed row.

Comment: can we stay in touch?

Comment: @Fabien Sure. My main system is in for repairs, so I don't have much of my social media hooked up except on my phone, but I do check my email pretty regularly: brianmfear at gmail.

Comment: Got it thanks , you are already in my list of true friends x !  
Btw , do you know how to get this sorted? how to retrieve all deleted rows ? the id of the element which has been deleted ? i tried with `filter` but it doesnt work

Comment: @Fabien splice removes the values from the array and returns those deleted elements. `let deletedRows = this.caseDefaultData.splice(event.target.dataset.index, 1);` This should be an Array of length=1. The second line of code remaps the rowNumber so it is linear.

Comment: yes its with length 1 but my goal is to retrieve all deleted elements ( obj )

Comment: @Fabien You need to keep track of each row that's deleted, or have the original data to compare to.

Comment: something like this : `const result = this.caseDefaultData.filter(item => this.originalData.find((data)=>data.Id!==row.Id);`

Comment: @Fabien No, it'd look something more like: `const existingIds = new Set(this.originalData.map((data) => data.Id));
const deletedIds = this.caseDefaultData.filter(
  (data) => !existingIds.has(data.Id)
);
`

Comment: `deletedIds` returns empty array everytime i delete a row –

Comment: even with this : `const deletedIds = this.caseDefaultData.filter((data) => data.Id != existingIds );`  didnt workd..

Comment: @Fabien Wouldn't expect that to to work. I'll write up an example later this afternoon.

Comment: i'm so dumb , can't even figure out how it can be working !! i shouldn't disturb you every time i'm facing an issue ,sorry, dont know what to do in my career i'm not a real developer !! i'll be waiting for your answer but THANKS SO MUCH BRIAN !!!!!

Comment: @Fabien You're just a beginner. Give it time. In the meantime, I updated the [previous demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/VZgYTjQnBfHGVHILp0Uk/src/app.js?p=stories) to include an Id property so you can see how to track which items are deleted, and included some output for that.

Comment: Thanks bruh , it works , why you puted [0] in `this.deletedRows = [...this.deletedRows, this.filters.splice(index, 1)[0]];`  ?

Comment: @Fabien Because splice returns an array, but we only need the first item, as we're only ever deleting one row at a time. Thinking about it though, we could also write `this.deletedRows = [...this.deletedRows, ...this.filters.splice(index, 1)];` if that makes it make more sense.

Comment: Brian , have you 10min please? the `modifiedFilters` doesnt work anymore ..

Comment: Brian? are you free for 10min?

Comment: Brian , do you have some time for me plz